# what can we do if our desireddomain.desiredextension is kept under reservered by godday hosting service

Tags: dns, web, hosting, reserved

what can we do if our desireddomain.desiredextension is kept under reservered by godday hosting service. can we buy that?.If it so then how

Comment: This is a question for godaddy(?) support...

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this isn't for this forum, you should ask godaddy. But for most cases, if a subdomain is owned by godaddy you mean? I don't know what you mean... If you want a subdomain, then you gotta contact the domain owner and ask.... If you would LIKE a domain owned by godaddy, then usually you can go to godaddy or any name registrar, type it in and then click place offer or place bet. This will notify the owner of the domain that you would like to buy the domain and then you can negotiate a price.

Good luck